# Showing popup only when the incoming post is not the user's. Firebase / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Exactly like on Twitter I've got a little bubble that appears at the top of my view when new posts come in that prompt the user to do a pull to refresh.

I'm basing this all off a .value observer of a "invitedPosts" node in Firebase. When a user receives or sends a post, the information gets sent into this invitedPosts section. The reason the post the user sends himself is sent to invitedPosts is simply because it makes the rest of my app so much easier to work with..this is the one exception. Refactoring at this point would be a massive rework of the whole app.

I obviously don't want for this bubble to show up when a user posts, so I figured I'd handle this client side by something like this. (Pseudo code)

```
//User hits the post button, sets a bool to false
func takingAPictureForPost(){
self. shouldCheckForPosts = false
}
//AVCapture session has taken the photo, information is sent to Firebase
func pictureTakenAndPostDataAvailableToSendToFirebase(){

 firebase.setValue(post)

 }

 //Checks against shouldCheckForPosts before making a bubble

 invitedPostsRef.observe(value){
  if shouldCheckForPosts {
    makeNotification()
  } else {
 //If it was false because the user just made the post, set it back to true so new posts can be seen.
    shouldCheckForPosts = true
   }

 }
 }
```

The glaring problem with this is if at the beginning of the posting process to firebase, asynchronously a node from inviteToPosts gets added to deleted, and that "eats up" the check for shouldCheckForPosts, so then when the user finishes posting it shows the notification for their own post.

I would just like to use .childAdded and check the actual userUID on the post vs my logged in user's, but childAdded does an initial check on every single node which triggers once for each, so the notification is then fired off a million times initially, and I don't see a way to run code after childAdded is done running through all of the initial children. At that point I'd just set a "firstTimeLoad" bool to check against to prevent the notifications from popping up during that first mass check, then check each incomming childAdded against my usersUID.

How should I do this?

Any ideas on how best to do this?

Comment: When a post is posted do you include the uid of the user that made the post?

Comment: Sorry, had to leave for a bit. Yes I do. I was thinking maybe I could grab the .value, order child by timestamp, get the most recent one, and if that UID matches my user's UID then I wouldn't show the bubble, otherwise go for it?

Comment: If you are adding an observer to a node, and you know you want to ignore the ones from 'this' user, then when you receive the snapshot, and it's got this users ui as a child, ignore it and don't add it to your datasource. There are other ways of doing it but that's the simplest based on the question.